# How do I change until the next underscore in VIm?

Tags: vim

If I have this text in vim, and my cursor is at the first character:

```
www.foo.com
```

I know that I can do:

- `cw` to change up to the first period, because a `word` (lowercase w) ends at any punctuation OR white space
- `cW` to change the whole address, because a `Word` (uppercase w) ends only at whitespace

Now, what if I have this:

```
stupid_method_name
```

and want to change it to this?

```
awesome_method_name
```

Both `cw` and `cW` change the whole thing, but I just want to change the fragment before the underscore.

My fallback technique is `c/_`, meaning 'change until you hit the next underscore in a search,' but for me, that also causes all underscores to be highlighted as search terms, which is slightly annoying.

**Is there a specifier like `w` or `W` that doesn't include underscores?**

Comment: What's wrong with `:nohl`?

Comment: I **do** want search terms to be highlighted most of the time; just not when I use search as a movement. (I also just asked this question: http://superuser.com/questions/244042/is-it-possible-to-not-trigger-my-normal-search-highlighting-when-using-search-as)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can do `cf_`. f won't highlight the searched character.

You can also do `ct_` if you don't want to include the _.

Comment: This is also incredibly extendable and therefore powerful. I'm guessing you can put any character after the f or t and it will go to the next (or prev for caps) occurrence. Thanks.

Comment: Mnemonic: `change 'til`.

i.e. `ct_` can be remembered as "change 'til underscore".

Answer (score 82):

Put this in your .vimrc:

`set iskeyword-=_`

Then _ will be treated as a word boundary (though not a WORD boundary), and cw could be used to just change "awesome", and cW to change the whole thing.

See:

`:help iskeyword`

and

`:help word`

for more info.

Comment: It's great to know that I can define my own word boundaries, but after some thought, I think the best solution is `ct_` as doubleface says below, since it's concise and is default vim behavior.

Comment: I like this one, but it breaks my syntax color coding in php.

Comment: How can I unset or toggle this?

Comment: I don't understand how come it took me so long to suffer through not having this directive set :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

[camelcasemotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) is a pretty handy vim plugin that allows you to move through words when using underscore or camelcase notation. Using this plugin you can place a comma in front of many of the traditional vim motion commands which will allow you to treat words in underscore or camelcase notation as full words.

Answer (score 1):

As a summary of all previous answers:

> There is no specifier to exclude `_`

You can do `cf_`. The searched character (`_` here) will be included in the replaced string.
You can also do `ct_` if you don't want to include the searched character (`_` here).

- `f` and `t` won't highlight the searched character in the file, unlike `/`.
- `f` and `t` allows to search for *one* character
- `/` will allow for a pattern or a longer string , and will not include it, like `t`

Comment: If you intend to add more information to an answer, just extend / modify it. Do not copy its content and post it as an own answer. This is plagiarism.

Comment: @dirdi I agree. I tried to edit the first answer, but it was rejected and suggested to post on my own.