# Is it possible to not trigger my normal search highlighting when using search as a movement?

Tags: vim

When I do a search in vim, I like to have my results highlighted and super-visible, so I give them a bright yellow background and a black foreground in my `.vimrc`.

```
" When highlighting search terms, make sure text is contrasting colors
:highlight Search guibg=yellow guifg=black
```

(This is for GUI versions of vim, like MacVim or Gvim; for command-line, you'd use `ctermbg` and `ctermfg`.)

But I sometimes use search with a command, as in `c/foo` - "change from the cursor to the next occurrence of `foo`."

In that case, I don't want all the occurrences of `foo` to be highlighted.

Can I turn off highlighting **only** in cases where search is used as a movement for a command?

Comment: If there's no way to make this a default, is there a way to have an alternate search that doesn't highlight? Like, instead of `c/foo`, `c//foo`, where `//` is a non-highlighting search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These naive mappings seem to help.

- **normal search**

  Turn highlighting *on* before doing the search:

  ```
  nnoremap / :set hls<CR>/
  ```
- **motion search**

  Turn highlighting *off* before doing the search:

  ```
  nnoremap v/ :set nohls<CR>v/
  nnoremap d/ :set nohls<CR>d/
  nnoremap y/ :set nohls<CR>y/
  nnoremap c/ :set nohls<CR>c/
  ```

Note that you'd need to setup similar mapping for `?`.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to fully explore this suggestion yet, but it may work and at least points me in the right direction. I'd say that deserves the bounty. :)

Answer (score 1):

To permanently disable highlighting of searches:

```
:set nohlsearch
(or)
:set nohls
```

But probably you want to keep highlight on. On the other hand, if want to temporary get rid of the highlight, type:

```
:nohlsearch
(or)
:noh
```

It will stop highlighting the current search, until you search again.

Even though it's not the perfect answer for you, this is a nice workaround, and this is what I use.

Comment: Actually, I've got an even shorter shortcut for "clear my current search highlighting": I just hit enter if I'm in normal mode. This line is in my .vimrc: `:nnoremap <CR> :nohlsearch<CR>/<BS>`. It clears the highlighting, starts a new search, and then backspaces to abort the search (thereby clearing the search bar so things look normal again.) This is pretty easy, but I'm so lazy that if I could avoid even having to hit enter, I would like that. :)

Comment: I got an even easier shortcut: `Alt+/` mapped to `nnoremap <M-/> :nohlsearch<CR>`  (note: `Alt+/` does not work on some terminals, but works well inside gvim)

Comment: I don't quite get it. What do you type and what happens?

Comment: I've added the remapping thing to my `.vimrc`. Then, whenever I want to temporary disable the highlighting, I press Alt+/, which is the shortcut to which I mapped it.

Comment: Also... as I said, it's a workaround, not exactly a solution.

Comment: `hlsearch` is "off" by default, no need to urn it "off".